# RewriteCond for either www.mysite.com or mysite.com?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

What's the appropriate RewriteCond for either www.mysite.com or mysite.com?

I tried this, but I'm getting a redirection error in my browser

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.mysite|mysite)\.com [NC]
```

**EDIT**

```
<Directory /var/www/maintenance/public_html>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteOptions inherit
        RewriteEngine on
        #
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/. http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: That will do it.  But yeah, if you're redirecting all requests based on that condition as discussed in your [previous question](http://serverfault.com/q/400386), then you're going to send them into a redirect loop.  Please provide that full config in this question as well.  That config will always result in a redirect loop; you're not letting it serve content.  Are you intending to redirect for all requests except those to the root (`http://www.example.com/`)?

Comment: Yah I'm intending to redirect all requests except those to the root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've removed your other question, which actually has the detail about the problem. Your RewriteCond is correct for matching both those hostnames, the problem is that you are redirecting `http://www.mysite.com/` to `http://www.mysite.com/`, which is where the loop is coming from. You need to only redirect if the request is NOT for `http://www.mysite.com/`. You probably need two rules for this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The first rule only operates on mysite.com, and redirects everything to `http://www.mysite.com/`. The second rule only operates on www.mysite.com and redirects everything other than `/` to `http://www.mysite.com/`. (The `.` means match one of any character -- since `/` doesn't have any other characters, it won't match.)

Comment: Ah thanks - so the first condition works as intended (`mysite.com/subdir/subpage.php` redirects to `www.mysite.com`), but the 2nd one doesn't redirect (`www.mysite.com/subdir/subpage.php` loads and does not redirect to `www.mysite.com`)

Comment: @user784637 Try my modified pattern in the answer.

Comment: That's because it's inside a `<Directory >` block.  Either move it outside or remove the slash from the rewrite rule. (Or add a question mark after it I guess.)

Comment: Michael - I tried your most recent edit and get `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`.  I then tried Ladada's suggestion, but it did not redirect any use case I tried.  I'm editing the directive in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site_maintenance`

Comment: @user784637 Remove the space between the `!` and `^`.

Comment: Thanks Michael, sorry for the newb factor, I really appreciate your help today and yesterday